# How can I prevent the consumable in-app purchases to be restored in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have 6 consumable in-app purchases set in my app. The app is in production and everything works fine. Now I want to submit an update, but when I try to buy the first consumable with a sandbox account it says that it's restoring it. The thing is that I do not want it restored since what I am selling is in-app credits.
I can see in iTunes Connect that: "An In-App Purchase has been returned and is highlighted in the table below, but no in-app purchase is highlighted."

The code for the in-app purchases hasn't been changed. The app that is in production worked fine since I tested all the in-app purchases and didn't encounter this problem.
Can this be an error from the part of Apple, or am I doing something wrong?

And if it's not an error from Apple, how can I prevent consumable in-app purchases being restored?